# allow mixed http over https on chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, https, development-environment

I would like to run a dev resource that is in my localhost via a chrome extension I develop (for debugging).
As understood my extension cannot call localhost (my dev environment) because it runs on http and not https, as most sites are today.
Is there a way that I can run my extension and access my local dev environment?

Comment: Extensions can call localhost via http. Your question should have [MCVE](/help/mcve) to help you and us diagnose the problem.

Comment: the extension add a sidebar with an iframe that is directed to localhost in http. In the console we get the mixed http, https error.

Comment: Without [MCVE](/help/mcve) all we can do is guess randomly, which is why such questions get closed.